# What's a less repetitive way to convert c structs to matlab structs?

Tags: c, matlab, struct, mex

i have a c structure that i need to convert to a matlab structure.
the fields have different types, and some are arrays.
i'm looking for a way to do it that has the minimum boilerplate/repeated information.

```
typedef struct {
  UINT32 time ;
  double px[2];
} data_s;

data_s   s;    
mxArray *fieldVal      ,
        *structArrayPtr;

structArrayPtr = mxCreateStructMatrix(1, 1, numFields, fieldNames);
```

i'm trying to replace the following, which is too repetitive.

```
fieldVal = mxCreateNumericMatrix(1, 1, mxUINT32_CLASS, mxREAL);
mxGetData(fieldVal)[0] = s.time;
mxSetField(structArrayPtr, 0, "time", fieldVal);

fieldVal = mxCreateNumericMatrix(1, 2, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
mxGetData(fieldVal)[0] = s.px[0];
mxGetData(fieldVal)[1] = s.px[1];
mxSetField(structArrayPtr, 0, "px", fieldVal);
```

the idea is something like this.

```
typedef struct {
    char *name ;
    int   type ;
    int   arity;
} fields_s;

const fields_s fields[] = {
    {"time", mxUINT32_CLASS, 1},
    {"px"  , mxDOUBLE_CLASS, 2}
};

void *tmp;

for (i = 0; i < numFields; i++) {
    fieldVal = mxCreateNumericMatrix(1, fields[i].arity, fields[i].type, mxREAL);
    switch (i) {
        case 0: tmp = &(s.time); break;
        case 1: tmp =   s.px   ; break; // don't take address of arrays
    }

    // hmm, can't sizeof() on a dereferenced void*.  
    // any solution other than repeating the field name?
    // and does this make bad assumptions about data representation being the same?
    memcpy(mxGetData(fieldVal), tmp, sizeof(*tmp) * fields[i].arity);

    mxSetField(structArrayPtr, 0, fields[i].name, fieldVal);
}
```

even if that would work, it is unsatisfying because we have to manually line up the field names and have to use different syntax depending on whether each is an array.

Comment: whats wrong with putting it in a class?

Comment: you can probably build a constructor to initialize all those variables as well

Comment: this is c, not c++, but how would that help?

Comment: But you said you want to convert c structs to matlab structs. If you're simply prototyping different initial inputs (the example you gave being "too repetitive"), then Classes/Objects seem to be a good solution. Matlab has object/class support.

Comment: oh, this is integrating into an existing framework that doesn't use matlab's classes.  but how would using classes help in getting the c data into matlab anyway?  the data is coming in from physical equipment via c (and speed is at a premium).

Comment: Well if you're going to use Matlab, you might as well use it's benefits. But if you don't wish to, you can always create a function that will initialize the variables for you right?

Comment: can you provide a code example?  i am sucking in data from equipment via a c api, and need access to it from a matlab framework that i didn't write or design.  it starts off as a c struct, and the framework needs it to be a matlab struct.  i am not seeing how your line of advice applies to this problem.

Comment: Okay I don't see any piece of Matlab code here. Maybe we have different definitions of Matlab Structs. Can you confirm this structure is what you want?
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html

Comment: Also, how does mex fit in? I've never worked with mex'ed code in C before.

Comment: [mxCreateStructMatrix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcreatestructmatrix.html) is creating one of those structs.  [mex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mex) is the fastest way to access data in c from matlab.

Comment: I know what mex is, I've just never used it. If it's all to be done in `C`, this isn't my area of expertise then :/

Comment: It's really not worth the complication.  Just go the verbose route.  But your can build a map from classid (e.g. `mxUINT32_CLASS`) to element size if your determined to write some machinery for this problem that you can separate from the output specs.

Comment: BTW, this might be of interest, although it's really quite hackish in this application: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstddef/offsetof/

Comment: this is a small example, but the real struct is large and contains large arrays.  the verbose route isn't practical.

Comment: There is no easy way in C to avoid repetition in this scenario. The best I can think of is to prepare macros to reduce lines of codes.